# ASP.NET process recycling and session variables

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to be clear what is meant by the text below on the following webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525803%28v=vs.90%29.aspx:

> Occurrence of multi-instancing: In multi-instancing, two or more instances of a process run simultaneously. Depending on how the application pool is configured, it is possible for multiple instances of a worker process to run, each possibly loading and running the same application code. The occurrence of an overlapped recycle is an example of multi-instancing, as is a Web garden in which two or more processes serve the application pool regardless of the recycling settings.

I am developing an ASP.NET app that I believe has this problem i.e. there was a case today where it appears that a session variable was shared accross two sessions.  I believe this could be because the process was recycled (only an idea).

Comment: Sharing session variables is not something that you'll ever see outside of custom state servers, so my guess is that while your two sessions *appeared* to share data, it was just an appearance. However, without more background it's just a guess, and not even an educated one. This might give you more background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623551/can-you-share-the-session-variables-between-two-net-2-0-applications

Comment: @Heather, what happens if the session recycles? Are you able to put what you aid in an answer?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean when you say "session recycles". If you are using the built-in state management, then a "session" is nothing more than a cookie on the remote browser that references a memory collection in the web server. If the server restarts or the user clears cookies, the session is lost. This is a pretty good overview of IIS session management:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478989.aspx