# Session lock and response.flush

Tags: asp.net

Does Response.Flush have any affect on the session state of an application? For example, if the response is flushed then could the session lock be removed?

I am experience what appears to be an occasional session collision as described in my question here: [ASP.NET - Accessing web page twice from client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980123/asp-net-accessing-web-page-twice-from-client).  The session collision appears to occur on a web page, which flushes the response periodically.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming i understand your question.

No it has no effect on the Session State.`Response.Flush` sends the output immediately to the client. It has nothing to do with the Session State.

> MSDN Response.Flush Method - The Flush method sends buffered output immediately.

- [MSDN - Response.Flush Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525560%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know what could cause session variables to be shared.  I was thinking about the IIS process recycling?

Comment: What you mean with "to be shared" ?

Comment: Please see the question I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980123/asp-net-accessing-web-page-twice-from-client.